# How to split an email address into its parts before and after dot (.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
1. Mailid
-------------------------------
John.smith@gmail.com
Robert.Janice@gmail.com
info.Robert@gmail.com
info-Janice.Robert@gmail.com
info_Janice.Robert@gmail.com
Don.Janice_Robert@gmail.com
```

*2 .Need firstname and lastname from email address before and after . dot record. *
*How to split an email address*
     'SELECT LEFT(mail, CHARINDEX('@', mail) - 1) AS fullname '

```
   'select  substring( mail, 1, charindex('.', mail)-1) as firstname,
substring(  mail,   charindex('.',  mail) + 1, LEN(' mail') ) as lastname
from admintable '

 3.    FirstName                 lastName   
-------------------  ----------   
John                    smith      
Robert                  Janiceh
info                    Robert     
info-Janice             Robert
info_Janice             Robert   
Done                   JaniceRobert
```

Comment: What about a person with no `.` prior to the `@`? What about a someone with 2 or more? With about an email address like `'Smith.John@msn.com'`? Would you class that person as having a "firstname" of "Smith"?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the split_string function (which was introduced in SQLSERVER  2016),

you can do the following->

*I have broken it into stages for you using a CTE, you can combine them all but this allows you to see each part and you can make a function which will mimic the split_string function:*

```html
WITH D AS
  (SELECT 'ABC.DEF@XXXXX.XXXXXX' AS email)

SELECT LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('.', email + '.') - 1) AS FORENAME, --characters left of the '.'
 RIGHT(email, LEN(email)-CHARINDEX('.', email)) AS SURNAME -- characters to the right of the '.'

FROM
  (SELECT LEFT(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1) AS EMAIL -- Removes the @xxxxx.xxxx leaving the name as a string
   FROM D) AS sub
```

Answer (score 0):

below should work, you were fairly close but you needed the length difference between the '@' and the '.'

NOTE: I added [] around the fieldName [mail] just to clarify that it is a fieldName but not required.

```
    SELECT
     SUBSTRING([mail], 1, CHARINDEX('.', [mail])-1) AS FirstName
    ,SUBSTRING([mail], CHARINDEX('.', [mail]) + 1, CHARINDEX('@', [mail]) - CHARINDEX('.', [mail]) -1 ) AS LastName
    ,SUBSTRING([mail], 1, CHARINDEX('.', [mail])-1) + ' ' + SUBSTRING([mail], CHARINDEX('.', [mail]) + 1, CHARINDEX('@', [mail]) - CHARINDEX('.', [mail]) -1 ) AS FullName
    FROM [admintable]
```

*Edited to add FullName as you mentioned something to do with FullName in your question, although I'm not sure if it was needed, remove if not

Answer (score 0):

This will work. I broke it into parts to include the full name

```
DECLARE @Mail TABLE (Mailid VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @Mail VALUES
('John.smith@gmail.com'),('Robert.Janice@gmail.com'),
('info.Robert@gmail.com'),('info-Janice.Robert@gmail.com'),
('info_Janice.Robert@gmail.com'),('Don.Janice_Robert@gmail.com');

SELECT
Mailid
,LEFT(Mailid,CHARINDEX('@',Mailid)-1) FULL_Name
,LEFT(LEFT(Mailid,CHARINDEX('@',Mailid)-1),CHARINDEX('.',LEFT(Mailid,CHARINDEX('@',Mailid)-1))-1)AS FirstName
,RIGHT(LEFT(Mailid,CHARINDEX('@',Mailid)-1),
LEN(LEFT(Mailid,CHARINDEX('@',Mailid)-1))-LEN(LEFT(LEFT(Mailid,CHARINDEX('@',Mailid)-1),
        CHARINDEX('.',LEFT(Mailid,CHARINDEX('@',Mailid)-1))))) AS lastName 

FROM @Mail
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the full name is delimited by only one `•`, you can also use `parsename` for this

```
select 
mailid,
parsename(replace(mailid,'@','.'),4) as firstname,
parsename(replace(mailid,'@','.'),3) as lastname
from admintable;
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to use the STRING_SPLIT function.

EDIT: Link to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Example:

```
SELECT name FROM STRING_SPLIT('firstname.lastname','.');
```

Output:

```
name:
firstname
lastname
```

Hopefully this make sense. The first parameter you put into this function is the string, and the second parameter is what you want to split on, in this case a '.' character.

Comment: Please post an example of how to use the function, and a reference to the documentation

Comment: You should expand on this answer and show the OP how to implement this function if you think it should be used. This, on it's own, won't help the OP answer their question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I included a link to the documentation in my answer now :)

Comment: Good, now you should add an example of how to use the function

Comment: I added my example hopefully this explains it well enough

Comment: This would pivot the data, cause the firstname and last name to be on 2 different rows; which is not what the OP is after.